# Does the integral converge? $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\;{\sin{(1/x)}\;{(x-\cos{(\pi/x)})}^{-2}}\;\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, closed-form

Please help me check, whether the following integral converges or not:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\sin{\left(1\over x\right)}\over{(x-\cos{\left(\pi\over x\right)})}^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
It seems to me, that it doesn't converge. However I can't prove it. The $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}{\sin{\left(1\over x\right)}\over{(x-\cos{\left(\pi\over x\right)})}^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
part seems to converge, because the integrand is equivalent to
$${{1\over x}\over{(x-(1-{\left(\pi\over x\right)}^2))}^2} \sim {1\over x^3}$$
for $x\to+\infty;{1\over x}\to0$. The
$$\int_{0}^{1}{\sin{\left(1\over x\right)}\over{(x-\cos{\left(\pi\over x\right)})}^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
part is what I am having problems with. There are infinitely many critical values, when $x\in(0;1)$. Even worse is that I don't even know, how to find a closed form solution to $x = \cos{\left(\pi\over x\right)}$. So splitting it into a sum of integrals with bounds at critical values doesn't work.

Since I thought, that it diverges, I figured the integral might diverge on the interval $(a;1)$, where $a\approx0.5882$, which is the last root of $x = \cos{\left(\pi\over x\right)}$. But even if I knew the exact value of $a$,
$$\int_{a}^{1}{\sin{\left(1\over x\right)}\over{(x-\cos{\left(\pi\over x\right)})}^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
for $x\to a$ doesn't seem to simplify to anything useful, since there is no way to know, how would $x$ and $\cos{\left(\pi\over x\right)}$ behave in this region.

Comment: this integral does not converge

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thank you, good sir. I was pretty sure of that since I saw the crazy wobbles near 0, but the question still stands: how to prove it. I might be missing something completely obvious.

Comment: have you tried $x\rightarrow 1/x$?

Comment: @tired I don't understand, sorry. $x\to 1/x$ is $x\to 1$. Isn't it? Or do you mean replacing $x = 1/t; dx = -dt/t^2;$ and so on?

Comment: @ruro the second option

Comment: @tired Well, that would leave me with $(t\cos{(\pi t)} - 1)^2$ in the denominator which also doesn't have closed form solutions for $t \in (1;+\infty)$.